# Create a list and append objects created from function arcpy.Exists through a loop

Tags: arcpy

I used a SearchCursor object to create a list 
 containing file paths and saved the list to a variable called `FilePathList`.

Next, I iterated through elements within the list using a `for` loop. Within the `for` loop, I nested an `if` statement that contains the `arcpy.Exists` function. I am inserting elements from the `FilePathList` into the `arcpy.Exists` function. When list elements are inserted into the function, if the element exists a data object string “1” is created. In addition, if the element does not exist a data object string "0" is created. I read that the `arcpy.Exists()` function returns a Boolean indicating whether the element exists.

I want to use the `arcpy.Exists` function to create string objects "1" representing exists and "0" representing does not exist. In the code below, I am able to print the string objects one by one, in the correct order, to the console. However, I would like to append the strings to an empty list in the order that they are printed. The order is important because I will eventually insert the created list into a new field within the dbf file. The field needs to be in the correct order because it corresponds and links to another field.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

#dbf table used for processing
dbf = "C:\\TestFolder\\ProcessControlTable.dbf"
#Column within dbf table containing file paths 
myColumn = "FI_PATH"
#Temp list created to hold appended items from arcpy.Exists Function
Temp = []

#SearchCursorList created by using SearchCursorObject to create List 
FilePathList =[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf,myColumn)]
print(FilePathList)
for elements in FilePathList:
    if arcpy.Exists(elements):
        #If element in SearchCursorList Exists;
        #Define a variable called Exists and string object
        Exists = "1"
        Temp.append(Exists[0])
        print(Exists)

    else:
        DoesNotExist = "0"
        Temp.append(Exists[0])
        print(DoesNotExist)

print (Temp)
```

The output in the Python shell first prints the list containing file paths.
Next, strings created from looping with the `arcpy.Exists` function are printed one by one in the correct order. Lastly, the `Temp` list is printed however all items in the list are the string object '1'. I want `Temp` list to contain strings created from the `arcpy.Exists` function looping in the correct order. The `Temp` list should print ['1','1','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','0']

[image: Python Shell Output]

I'm not sure what code will pull objects out of the loop and put it into a new list. I can't think of the logic with my limited Python and ArcPy knowledge.

Comment: In your "else", you use a different variable name to store the result than you use to append to the list. This causes the printed values to be different from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "else", you use a different variable name to store the result than you use to append to the list. This causes the printed values to be different from the list.

Some other suggestions:

1. Naming conventions in Python recommend using lowercase, and in some cases, mixedCase for variables. Some specific recommendations are found in the PEP8 guidelines.
   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions
2. The line `Temp.append(Exists[0])` appends the first character of the string contained in the `Exists` variable. this isn't needed since you want to append a single character string; in other words, you can drop off the `[0]` in this line.

Incorporating these changes:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

#dbf table used for processing
dbf = "C:\\TestFolder\\ProcessControlTable.dbf"
#Column within dbf table containing file paths 
myColumn = "FI_PATH"
#Temp list created to hold appended items from arcpy.Exists Function
temp = []

#SearchCursorList created by using SearchCursorObject to create List 
filePathList =[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf,myColumn)]
print(filePathList)
for elements in filePathList:
    if arcpy.Exists(elements):
        #If element in SearchCursorList Exists;
        #Define a variable called Exists and string object
        exists = "1"    
    else:
        exists = "0"
    # can move these out of the loop since they are performed for both cases
    temp.append(exists) 
    print(exists)

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this might serve your eventual purpose:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

#dbf table used for processing
dbf = "ProcessControlTable.dbf" # you don't need the full path because it's in the current workspace
#Column within dbf table containing file paths 
myColumn = "FI_PATH"

arcpy.AddField_management(dbf,'DoesExist','STRING')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dbf,[myColumn,'DoesExist']) as uCur:
    for uRow in uCur:
        if arcpy.Exists(uRow[0]):
            uRow[1]='1'
        else:
            uRow[1]='0'
        uCur.updateRow(uRow)

# select the non-existing into a new table
arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(dbf,'DataNotExist.dbf',"DoesExist = '0'")
```

This adds a field 'DoesExist' to your dbf table then iterates the table recording if the dataset is found in the full path and finally extracts a table for just the files that don't exist. Beware though a 2nd iteration will fail at the add field stage as the field already exists.

Another viable option is using a python dictionary, which stores value *pairs*, in this case (fullPath,Exists) using the full path for the dataset as the key and exists/not exists as the value:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

#dbf table used for processing
dbf = "ProcessControlTable.dbf" # you don't need the full path because it's in the current workspace
#Column within dbf table containing file paths 
myColumn   = "FI_PATH"
ExistsDict = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf,myColumn) as sCur:
    for sRow in sCur:
        if arcpy.Exists(sRow[0]):
            ExistsDict[sRow[0]]='1'
        else:
            ExistsDict[sRow[0]]='0'

for FC in ExistsDict: # loop through each dataset path and print if exists
    print '{} exists value {}'.format(ExistsDict[FC])
```